# python numpy dict to nparry and IndexError: only integers, slices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I made np.array as below

```
test = np.array({'a': 1})
```

and I just want get value of test by key 'a' as below

```
test['a']
```

and I faced error as below

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

how can i get value of key 'a' in np.array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first take the `dict` out of the array:

```
In [142]: test = np.array({'a': 1})
In [143]: test
Out[143]: array({'a': 1}, dtype=object)
In [144]: test.item()
Out[144]: {'a': 1}
In [145]: test.item()['a']
Out[145]: 1
```

But why did you make this?  Why not just a `dict`?  Or a list of `dict`.  `numpy` doesn't do much for you here.

Comment: thank you! To answer your question, its because I want write dict as binary file, and .npy file can that work. but when I load .npy, i faced problem.

Comment: When you use `np.save` on an object like a `dict`, it first embeds it in an object dtype array.  After all `np.save` is an array saving tool.  You could have used `pickle` to save the dict without the array wrapper.  There is a close connection between `pickle` and `np.save/load`.

Comment: oh I like your solution..! thank you. pickle is better for me